Ошибка при обращении серверу
Есть кусочек программы с запросом ( не уверена что он корректен)


try {
    const data = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/products", {
      method: "GET",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    });
    const response = await data.json();
  } catch (e) {
    throw e   
  }



и оттуда мне надо вытащить значения status и data


const responses = [{
  status: 200,
  data: {
    products,
  },
},
{
  status: 404,
  data: {
    products: [],
  },
},
{
  status: 500,
  data: {
    error: 'Server error',
  },
},
{
  status: 200,
  data: null,
},
];



подскажите, что я делаю не так и где у меня ошибка

Вот что дальше идет


if ((response.error = "Server error")) {
    let textError = "Произошла ошибка, попробуйте обновить страницу позже";
    errMes(textError);
  }

  if ((response.product = [] && response.error != "Server error")) {
    let textError = "Список товаров пуст";
    errMes(textError);
  }
  if (response.products) {
    for ....




Если так укажу то все правильно выводится


const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/products", {
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
  })




ты уже вытащил и сохранил в response.

response доступен внутри блока try, если надо вытащить выше, лучше в функцию обернуть и вернуть

а что ты пытаешься делать? Пока что все верно. Покажи код как ты пытаешься получить status и data

Используйте оператор сравнения. Вместо response.error = "Server error" -- response.error === "Server error" или  response.error == "Server error"

С response.product = [] та же ерунда, должно быть response.product == [] видимо. Ну и else надо бы писать, а то какая-то ерунда будет в итоге.

всем спасибо, разобралась
